# How to compare dates in sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I am writing a function that brings me all the matches of specific month and year.
I pass the month number and the year value to that function and it should use the following query to get the results:

```
SELECT tahminler.match_id, tahminler.tahmin_text,matches_of_comments.match_id
FROM tahminler
INNER JOIN matches_of_comments ON tahminler.match_id = matches_of_comments.match_id
WHERE (
matches_of_comments.match_date =  'I DO NOT KNOW WHAT TO WRITE HERE'
)
AND tahminler.user_id =12
```

The problem is the `matches_of_comments.match_date` type is varchar and i pass values of the month and year as numbers to make a form like `11.2013` how can i compare this form that i pass to the varchar date ?? can i convert the type into date ?? and if i can do that how to compare part of the date (just month and year)??

Comment: Well, what's the format of the date?  And it should really be stored as an actual date anyways...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one convert to date first then compare month and year ,note it is bad practiceto store date as varchar

```
SELECT tahminler.match_id, tahminler.tahmin_text,matches_of_comments.match_id
FROM tahminler
INNER JOIN matches_of_comments ON tahminler.match_id = matches_of_comments.match_id
WHERE (

MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(matches_of_comments.match_date , '%m/%d/%Y'))=  '07'//month variable
 AND YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(matches_of_comments.match_date , '%m/%d/%Y'))=  '2013'//year variable
)
AND tahminler.user_id =12
```

[**STR_TO_DATE(str,format)**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

[**MONTH**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month)

[**YEAR**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year)

Answer (score 0):

```
STR_TO_DATE('11.2013', '%m.%Y')
```

will convert the string into a datetime datatype. 
To compare in any format you need you can reformat it:

```
DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('11.2013', '%m.%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d')
```